# Using QSGTexture/QSGMaterial and Qt's RHI to implement a custom texture format for shaders

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

With Qt 6.2 there is a whole system of "graphics API independent" infrastructure (both on tooling and on C++ side) that enables you to render things in e.g. QML without writing one bit of Vulkan, Metal, Direct3D or OpenGL.

Based on [the "custom material" example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-scenegraph-custommaterial-example.html), and [QQuickWindow::createTextureFromImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qquickwindow.html#createTextureFromImage-1), I was able to render the image through a custom vertex and fragment shader to screen using OpenGL and Metal without altering my code. Great success!

But... the texture creation function converts the image to RGBA8/GL_RGBA, so using e.g. 16-bit or floating point images is impossible. The [QQuickWindow::createTextureFromImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qquickwindow.html#createTextureFromImage-1) documentation says:

> Reimplement QSGTexture to create textures with different parameters.

And [QSGTexture documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsgtexture.html#details) states:

> Materials that work with textures reimplement updateSampledImage() to provide logic that decides which QSGTexture's underlying native texture should be exposed at a given shader resource binding point.

The only way to see this using the provided API is by doing native graphics API calls and thus implementing my special format texture in both a QSGTexture and a QSGMaterialShader, for every graphics API I would want to support. This seems counter to the whole setup of what QRhi is supposed to provide (see e.g. [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/topics-graphics.html) for an overview).
Same for e.g. an additional texture, or a 3D texture, or anything else really, not covered by the simple vertex+fragment shader and single RGBA texture (granted they provide some support for mipmapping and anistrophic filtering.

Am I missing something? Will this improve in the future, or are we stuck actually still implementing the actual graphics API specific code for anything outside the "rendering simple UI through QML" case?
I suppose this same limitation exists for the Qt 3D module; anything outside of the supported scenarios is not implementable due to the underlying QRhi API not being public?

Comment: I wonder if you did find an answer to your question, and if it is possible for you to share your sample code with me?

Answer (score 0):

Qt 6 changed this part of the QSG API and implemented an example showing how to use the semi-public QRhi API to do custom rendering in a custom QSGRenderNode: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-scenegraph-customrendernode-example.html

This uses a few bits from private headers (in the sense that the API is not 100% stable, but they strive to keep it the same as much as possible) to set up a custom render pipeline which allows for various render backend independent resources.

It doesn't exactly implement a custom texture image format, but it allows you to upload a texture in whatever format you want and let your shaders process it in the way you want as part of rendering the scene graph, which I think is powerful enough.